# WordPress REST API with Vue.js - display ajax response, array not being updated

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm learning VueJS. I need to setup a Vue instance for a WordPress custom AJAX theme. I have this code, that I think will be ok. I want to render the pages of the WordPress site and then if the user click, load the content.

I'm using bootstrap 4 as my front-end framework

```
<div class="container-fluid content-wrapper">
  <div class="row" id="app">
<!-- Sidebar Top Area -->
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-5" id="navPanel">
<!-- Lista pagine -->
      <h1 class="home-claim" v-bind:title="pagename" v-for="page in pagenames" >
        {{ page.title.rendered }}
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-7" id="contentPanel">
<!-- contenuto pagine -->
    </div>
<!-- Sidebar Bottom Area -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      pagenames: []
    },
    mounted() {
      var self = this;
      var url = 'wp-json/wp/v2/pages';
      $.getJSON( url, function(data){
          self.pagenames = data.title.rendered;
          console.log(data.title.rendered);
        //console.log(data);
      });
    }
  });
```

I'm not able to display the page list. What's wrong?

Comment: There is no question in your thread 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After ajax response, you assign `data.title.rendered` string, to the Component's property `pagenames`previously defined as empty array. Assuming that `data` from response returns an array of pages/posts, you should be assigning full data instead:

```
 var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      pagenames: []
    },
    mounted() {
      var self = this;
      var url = 'wp-json/wp/v2/pages';
      $.getJSON( url, function(data){
          self.pagenames = data;
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: If I want to bind the ajax call to a click event I can use the same instance of vue, the code will goes into mounted funct?

Comment: Yes, wrap it with a method. And I guess that you will need to use some offset, to avoid loading the same list of posts each call.

Comment: Ok, I will do some tests, I want to render the content of the pages on click using the post or page ID. Thanks.